# Rspec don't recognise any method of RSpec::Matcher and RSpec::Core

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have spent 4 days trying to install Ruby on Rails properly but I have a big problem. The first time I used Linux (it's more confortable for me) but, after having a problem, I used windows. To my surprise, I have the same issue on Windows, so I suppose that I have forbidden something. If I try to load a page with a small form for a model, it shows me an error that says:

```
Unable to autoload constant ReservationsController, expected ...../app/controllers/reservations_controller.rb to define it
```

Also, if I try to execute a test for a model with rspec, I receive a lot of errors of the following type:

```
$ rspec spec/models/reservation_spec.rb 
FFFFF

Failures:

  1) Reservation Fields 
     Failure/Error: it{ should have_fields( :from_date ).of_type( Date ) }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `of_type' for #<RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::Has:0x915ebc8>
     # ./spec/models/reservation_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Reservation Fields 
     Failure/Error: it{ should have_fields( :price ).of_type( Float ) }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `of_type' for #<RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::Has:0x9423cc8>
     # ./spec/models/reservation_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) Reservation Fields 
     Failure/Error: it{ should have_fields( :room ).of_type( String ) }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `of_type' for #<RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::Has:0x94d5bbc>
     # ./spec/models/reservation_spec.rb:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) Reservation Fields 
     Failure/Error: it{ should have_fields( :until_date ).of_type( Date ) }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `of_type' for #<RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::Has:0x952cb60>
     # ./spec/models/reservation_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  5) Reservation Fields 
     Failure/Error: it{ should have_fields( :number_of_persons ).of_type( Integer ) }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `of_type' for #<RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::Has:0x957bbc0>
     # ./spec/models/reservation_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.16437 seconds
5 examples, 5 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/reservation_spec.rb:7 # Reservation Fields 
rspec ./spec/models/reservation_spec.rb:10 # Reservation Fields 
rspec ./spec/models/reservation_spec.rb:11 # Reservation Fields 
rspec ./spec/models/reservation_spec.rb:8 # Reservation Fields 
rspec ./spec/models/reservation_spec.rb:9 # Reservation Fields 

Randomized with seed 18738
```

The steps that I have followed to install rails are the following:

- Install Ruby 2.0.0.
- Install Git.
- Install Rails (following this page http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-ruby-on-rails-3/).
- Install MongoDB (following this page http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/).
- Install mongoid (add to Gemfile and use bundle install).
- Install rspec (add to Gemfile and use bundle install).
- Execute: rails generate rspec:install

The main files that I have used are the following:

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
require 'mongo'
source 'http://gemcutter.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'mongo_mapper'

gem "rspec-rails", :group => [:development, :test]
group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end

gem 'json',         '~> 1.8.0'  # Gem to support json
gem 'haml',         '~> 4.0.3'  # Gem to support haml views

gem 'mongo',        '~> 1.9.1'  # Gem to use mongodb
gem 'mongoid', git: 'https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid.git'

gem 'rake',         '~> 10.1.0' # Gem to use rake (rspec and cucumber)
gem 'cucumber',     '~> 1.3.5'  # Gem to test with cucumber
gem 'capybara',     '~> 2.1.0'  # Gem to use capybara in cucumber tests
gem 'wait_for',     '~> 0.1.1'  # Gem to wait for an apparition in cucumber tests
gem 'factory_girl', '~> 4.2.0'  # Gem to create examples data

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 4.0.0'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
  gem 'uglifier',     '~> 2.1.2'
end
```

**mongoid.yml**

```
development:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: hotel_development
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
  options:
test:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: hotel_test
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        consistency: :strong
        max_retries: 1
        retry_interval: 0
```

**mongo.rb**

```
MongoMapper.connection = Mongo::Connection.new('localhost', 27017)
MongoMapper.database = "#myapp-#{Rails.env}"

if defined?(PhusionPassenger)
  PhusionPassenger.on_event(:starting_worker_process) do |forked|
    MongoMapper.connection.connect if forked
  end
end
```

**reservation.rb**

```
class Reservation
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :from_date, type: Date
  field :until_date, type: Date
  field :number_of_persons, type: Integer
  field :price, type: Float
  field :room, type: String

  has_one :client
end
```

**reservations_controller.rb**

```
class ReservationsControlller < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find( params[:id] )
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new( params[:user] )
    if @user.save
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Hotel::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :reservations, only: [:show, :new, :create]
end
```

**reservation_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Reservation do
  subject{ @reservation }

  describe "Fields" do
    it{ should have_field( :from_date ).of_type( Date ) }
    it{ should have_field( :until_date ).of_type( Date ) }
    it{ should have_field( :number_of_persons ).of_type( Integer ) }
    it{ should have_field( :price ).of_type( Float ) }
    it{ should have_field( :room ).of_type( String ) }
  end
end
```

If you need another file I can put without problems.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Added rspec tests for reservation model.
EDIT2: I have included the output of the rspec test.

Comment: Are you using the mongoid-minitest gem as referenced in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18152278/where-is-the-have-fields-rspec-matcher-defined?

Answer (score 6):

You have three `l`s in your `ReservationsControlller` class name, which is why Rails is not finding the expected controller class when it loads the controller file. As for the rspec problem, perhaps you're missing an enclosing `describe`, but please share your spec so that we can see what's going on.

Update: Looking at your spec, you've set your `subject` to `@reservation`, but haven't initialized `@reservation`, so it's value will be `nil`. Also, since you used the class `Reservation` as the argument to the outer `describe`, the subject would implicitly be `Reservation.new` without the `subject` call.

As for the errors you're now getting, I'm not sure. `of_type` seems to be defined in `mongoid-rspec`, which you haven't explicitly included, but you're not getting an error from `have_fields`, which I thought was defined there as well. I don't see `have_fields` defined in the `mongoid-rspec` source, however, so perhaps that's coming from somewhere else. Anyway, I'd try adding the gem to see if that takes care of the problem.

Comment: Thanks!. I don't know why I haven't seen it before. Now I can load pages but tests continues failing. I have added the tests.

Comment: I know you shared errors from your testing earlier, but could you confirm that the errors you show above are exactly the errors you are seeing from running `reservation_spec.rb` or update the post to show those errors?