# Where is the have_fields RSpec matcher defined?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubygems, mongoid

A [recent question on using rspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132972/rspec-dont-recognise-any-method-of-rspecmatcher-and-rspeccore) featured some code with a `have_fields` matcher in it.

A search indicated that `have_fields` was referenced in the `mongoid-rspec` gem, but when I went to GitHub, I could only find it referenced in the spec files.

Similar searches of RSpec core and related gems came up empty as well.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for the [mongoid-minitest](https://rubygems.org/gems/mongoid-minitest) gem.

In [have_field.rb](https://github.com/frodsan/mongoid-minitest/blob/1dcb38c2196c4792eefbd07ba67cfc8d15107aad/lib/matchers/document/have_field.rb) it declares `have_fields` as an alias:

```
module Mongoid
  module Matchers
    module Document
      # TODO: Add documentation.
      def have_field *fields
        HaveFieldMatcher.new(*fields)
      end
      alias :have_fields :have_field

      private

      class HaveFieldMatcher < Matcher
        attr_reader :fields, :klass, :type, :default, :errors

        def initialize *fields
          @fields = fields.collect(&:to_s)
          @errors = []
        end

        def of_type type
          @type = type
          self
        end

        ... (rest of file omitted)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll ask the OP of the original question.